# I was trying to jailbreak my iPhone 4 (OS 4.3.5) but

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I was trying to jailbreak my iPhone 4 (OS 4.3.5) using this link http://www.redmondpie.com/jailbreak-4.3.5-ios-iphone-4-3gs-ipod-touch-4g-3g-ipad-1-using-redsn0w-how-to-tutorial/

The problem is that when I followed the steps, it isn't working

[image]

It has unrecognized specified IPSW.

The IPSW I downloaded from http://www.redmondpie.com/download-ios-4.3.5-for-iphone-4-3gs-ipad-2-1-and-pod-touch-direct-links/ iPhone 4 (GSM).

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a version of redsn0w that cannot handle that specific version of iOS. You will need to find the correct version.

Here is a guide that might help: http://technorati.com/technology/gadgets/article/how-to-jailbreak-ios-435-on/

And it is of note that they have not released an untethered jailbreak for either 4.3.4 or 4.3.5, which means you will have to load the IPSW in redsn0w and apple the crack (select the option "just boot tethered") every time you cycle the power.

Also of note that the redsn0w .8b series is reserved for the iOS 5 betas.

You can see the full list of versions here: https://sites.google.com/a/iphone-dev.com/files/home/

Off hand I don't remember which will jailbreak 4.3.5 but give the latest .6 series a try first and work backwards.

And a word of caution, be wary of Redmond Pie, fromy experience they are far from a credible source for help and frequently report inaccurate information or often times completely spread misinformation. They seem more concerned with "getting there first" than actually reporting steps that you can rely on.

Comment: after i've jail-breaked. they tell me to re-run redsn0w and boot tethered. what does that mean?

Comment: Like I said, you will need to open redsn0w and point it to the respective IPSW. Then when it comes time to select the jailbreaking options, you unhceck everything except for "just boot tethered right now". Your phone will freeze at the Apple logo if you do not perform this step, and fail to boot. A tethered JB requires the injection of the JB code each time the system restarts. Untethered jailbreaks have ways of injecting this code during boots without the need for an external program (redsn0w)